# How do I add a Touch Event to this UIScrollView Infinite Scroll Picker?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I'm using the InfiniteScrollPicker from GitHub https://github.com/Seitk/InfiniteScrollPicker/ in my project.  The way it works right now is when the scroll menu stops on a selection it automatically loads the storyboard scene.  I want to change it so that you have to tap on the menu image in order to load the storyboard scene instead of it happening on selection.  How would I do that?

I think this is the relevant code from InfiniteScrollPicker.m that I would need to change.  I'm thinking I would do it with some sort of gesture recognizer but I'm not sure where or how to add it to the code below.

```
    // Disable scrolling when snapping to new location
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(queue, ^ {
        [self setScrollEnabled:NO];
        [self scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(newX, 0, self.frame.size.width, 1) animated:YES];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {

            SEL selector = @selector(infiniteScrollPicker:didSelectAtImage:);
            if ([[self firstAvailableUIViewController] respondsToSelector:selector])
            {
                #pragma clang diagnostic push
                #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
                [[self firstAvailableUIViewController] performSelector:selector withObject:self withObject:biggestView.image];
                #pragma clang diagnostic pop
            }

            [self setScrollEnabled:YES];
            snapping = 0;
        });
```

This is part of the corresponding code from my ViewController.m

```
- (void)infiniteScrollPicker:(InfiniteScrollPicker *)infiniteScrollPicker didSelectAtImage:(UIImage *)buttonIndex
{    
    if (buttonIndex == [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_0.png"]) {

        NSLog(@"First Menu Item Selected");
        UIStoryboard *playGame = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *playGameVC = [gameOver instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayGame1"];
        [self presentModalViewController:playGameVC animated:YES];

    }
    if (buttonIndex == [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_1.png"]) {
        NSLog(@"Second Menu Item Selected");
        UIStoryboard *playGame = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *playGameVC = [gameOver instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameOverScene"];
        [self presentModalViewController:gameOverVC animated:YES];
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `UITapGestureRecognizer`, it is meant to recognize taps. Here is the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I had already looked at that. That's why I mentioned Gesture Recognizers.  That link doesn't help me with the current code because I not sure where to change with the current code.  The things I've tried didn't work.

Comment: I just tried adding this above the `SEL Selector` line and insider the `if` statement and neither option worked. `UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
            tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;`